# Cast to type from Type variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Unity. I have an

```
abstract class A {}
class A1 : A {object someField;}
class A2 : A {object someField;}
```

I have a CustomEditor where I create instances of A1/A2 with reflection (I need an ability to add new classes derived from A)
But there is a problem: if I use Activator like

```
Type chosenType = ChooseType(); //ChosenType can be A1 or A2
A newObj = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(chosenType)
```

Unity doesnt serialize that objects (because it serialize objects as (A) but not as (A1) or (A2))
I want to cast like

```
(chosenType)MyObj
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, If the chosenType is A1 then your object will be A1, until you cast it to A.

Comment: Unity has built in method for creating object there almost is never a reason to use reflection, Additionally it's not fully supported, It's slow,  and you can just use a factory.

Comment: @NibblyPig "chosenType" variable is dynamic (depends on what object I try to create via Inspector). And if Type variable could be inserted as generic parameter, I just create instance as Activator.CreateInstance<chosenType>() and get object of type chosenType. But it isn't allowed to use Type variable as generic parameter. Thats why I only allowed to cast. I dont know how can I cast object using only Type variable.

Comment: I know nothing of Unity.  However, if you execute your `(A)Activator.CreateInstance(chosenType)`, the new object will be of the appropriate type (`A1` or `A2`), but the variable will be typed as an `A`.  If all the methods, properties, etc that you want to access on A1 or A2 are there on A, then you are all set.  However, unless you do a possibly-failable cast to A1 or A2, all you will have is a reference to an object that you know is at least an A.  That's often good enough.

Comment: @johnny5 could you explain please? I need to have a method that allowes me create an object derived from class A, but also I prefer to keep them in List<A>.

Comment: @Flydog57 But I have different Layout drawings for A1/A2, because of different fields in these classes, thats why it isnt enough :>

Comment: If I understand it, this is primarily a serialization issue. Somewhere you have a collection of these objects, say an `A[]` or `List<A>`, but this collection has instances of various subclasses (or a mix thereof). For example, `List<A> myObjects = new List<A>() { new A1(), new A1(), new A2() };` But now, Unity (or the serializer you're using) is trying to serialize/deserialize them as `A` class, but not the derived types populated into that list at runtime?

Comment: Consider the case where A is `Shape` and your A1/A2 are Rectangle/Ellipse.  You can create a Rectangle or Ellipse in your fashion.  If shape has an abstract Rotate method, then when you rotate a Rectangle, you are rotating a Rectangle.  You keep everything in a `List<Shape>`.  Things more or less just work.  If you need to get the corner points on a Rectangle (i.e., something that doesn't make sense to an Ellipse), do an `as` cast to a Rectangle, and only get the corners if it succeeds

Comment: How are you serializing things.  Most serializers/deserializers are pretty good at this task (though I admit it's been a long time since I tried something like this)

Comment: @Magenta: If you're using Unity's built-in serialization, you may need to have your `A` base class be a `ScriptableObject`. That might fix it for you: https://answers.unity.com/questions/404679/properly-serialize-array-of-derived-classes.html

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes! Unity serializes them as A, thats why when I'm trying to get access to the A1/A2 fields - I get Exception.

Comment: @Magenta this is an X Y problem please explain what you're trying to accomplish, you are probably using the wrong data structure, e.g using a type instead of just having your layout options in a dictionary

Comment: @ChrisSinclair thank you, I'll check!

Comment: @johnny5 I ask if I can cast like (myTypeVariable)object in some way?

Comment: @Magenta, Yes but I'm saying that your problem isn't how to cast, it that you need to use reflection in the first place.  Why are you using reflection, there are other ways to create objects. Chances are you've picked a poor structure for your code and there is a way to solve this using a different architecture

Comment: @Flydog57 is correct, however unity serialisation does a poor job at storing the type   as-is, it serializes as the declared type which is the base class, so slicing occurs

Comment: @johnny5 is kinda academical interest

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've seen to dynamically do type casting like this is to create a generic like

```
public static class ReflectionHelper{

    public T CastTo<T>(object obj)
    {
        return (T) obj;
    }
}
```

And then to at runtime, create a generic method to cast to my specific type.

```
var value = Activator.CreateInstance(ChosenType());
typeof(ReflectionHelper)
.GetMethod("CastTo")
.MakeGenericMethod(new []{value.GetType()})
.Invoke(null, value);
```

In invoke, we call null because it's a static method, if it was an instance method we would need an instance of an object of type Reflection Helper.

However, I want to warn you doing these things tend to be a code smell, and I would urge you to only use reflection as your last resort not as your first go-to

Comment: So if I need to add this object to the List<> I still have the only way to cast it to parent class type, I think. If so — it isnt the solution.

Comment: Where in your question do you reference a list?

Comment: @JIalonde Yeah, its my fault, I'm sorry!

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you're trying to do

Comment: @Jlalonde I dont think this cast will help, the OP already created the proper type through reflection.  And it's to my understanding that unity does its serialization as part of the framework in the background